# how to parse Json data from a url in android? of this type

Tags: android, json, parsing, url

I followed [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parsing-yql-using-json-tutorial/) to parse JSON form URL

I what to parse json data from a url I almost done Parsing data but struck at 2 or 3 fields

like this

```
{
"returnCode": "success",
"ProductData": {
"results": [
  {
    "details": [
      {
        "latestoffers": [

        ],
        "offers_count": 0,
        "recentoffers_count": 0,
        "sku": "300",
        "url": "google.com"
      },
      {
        "latestoffers": [
          {
            "id": "5",
            "price": "311.95",
            "availability": "Available",
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        ],
        "offers_count": 1,
        "name": "b",
        "recentoffers_count": 1,
        "sku": "1",
        "url": "google.com"
      },
      {
        "latestoffers": [
          {
            "id": "2",
            "shipping": "8",
            "price": "299",
           }
        ],
        "sku": "856",
        "url": "google.com"
      }
    ],
.
    "gtins": [
      "58"
    ],
    .
    .
    .

    "features": {
    },
    "geo": [
      "usa"
    ],

    "images": [
      "google.com"
    ],

  }
],
"total_results_count": 1,
"results_count": 1,
"code": "OK",
 }
}
```

I parsed some fields which are in .(dot) I strucked at "details" latestoffers and images I don't know how to parse them I wasted lot of time...

give me any suggestion how to solve the above three details, latestoffers ,features,images..

its a lot of data I parsed nearly 60% but unable to parse some arrays and objects.. in android.

Comment: have a look at google and the great google made librarys `gson` (a json parser) and `volley` a great network lib

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html

Comment: Sir.. This is ok sir but I have 6 JSON files already parsed from jsonschema2pojo.com with GSON but I don't know how to use them I already followed vogella and GSON parsing please help how to parse this much of data with GSON or without GSON any help sir..

Comment: Include model classes you created in you project and try this link to parse using GSON http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Comment: also followed javacodegeeks sir,.. problem in xml and not getting images thanks for the help sir,.. please give me any other option sir,,

Comment: @user3073115 what datas you need from that json.

Comment: Highly recommende you to try `GSON`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
JSONObject objJson = new JSONObject(response);
String returnCode= objJson.getString("returnCode");
JSONObject objpro = objJson.getJSONObject("ProductData");
JSONArray arrresults = objpro.getJSONArray("results");

for(int i = 0;i<arrresults.length();i++){
    JSONObject obj = arrresults.getJSONObject(i);
    String url= obj.getString("url");
    JSONArray arrdeta = obj.getJSONArray("details");
    for(int k = 0;k<arrdeta.length();k++){
        JSONObject ObjJ = arrresults.getJSONObject(k);
        JSONArray arrlatest = ObjJ.getJSONArray("latestoffers");

        for(int j = 0;j<arrlatest.length();j++){
            JSONObject Jobj = arrlatest.getJSONObject(j);
            String currency= Jobj.getString("currency");
        }
    }
    JSONObject objfeatures = obj.getJSONObject("features");
     //Something inside features
    String some = arrimg.getString("some");
    JSONArray arrimg = obj.getJSONArray("images");
    for(int l = 0;l<arrimg.length();l++){
        String ima = arrimg.getString(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir I strucked at one place that what is JSONObject objJson = new JSONObject(response);/... I got error   response cannot be resolved to a variable.. But remaning all are Ok thanks sir.. But please tell me what is Response sir... how to over come that error..

Comment: @user3073115 `response` is your json in `String`.

Comment: I don't know what kind of data I am getting wether its response or result but it says it cannot be resolved as a variable please give any solution sir.. and what about this line sir,..String url= obj.getString("url");
Can you please send me with gmail my id:anand70.007@gmail.com

Comment: @user3073115 how did you get that json post that code i'll edit and i'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String jsonData= /*put your JsonData here*/
JSONObject objJson = new JSONObject(jsonData);

and String returnCode= objJson.getString("returnCode");

JSONArray ProductData= new JSONArray(objJson.getString("ProductData"));
```

you can access your data in the json.

if json has another json in data you can use the following line;

```
JSONObject innerObjJson = objJson.getJSONObject("InnerObjJsonName");
```

Comment: Sir this is fine sir,.. I am parsing data form url and I strucked at parsing these fields details, latestoffers ,features,images please help me for that sir.